# font-size is different in cross browsers

Tags: html, css

I have an issue that everyone knows it, but I don't have an answer yet:

`font-size` is different in all browsers.

I have the next jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/alonshmiel/0mtetsnr/4/

```
<div id="myDiv">
    <span class='Triangles'>&#9664;&#9654;</span>
</div>
```

I checked it in chrome and it looks good, but in explorer it looks bad.

In order to fix it, as I read, I have to define the font-size in px.

I defined it and it doesn't fix my problem.

p.s. I checked it in the same screen. the browsers are 100% zoom.

any help appreciated!

Comment: try to put the body to font-size: 62.5%; Then use em's. So font-size 1em would equal to 10px and 1.1em would equal to 12px. Try that and see if that helps.

Comment: Seems like you'd be better off using an icon-based font instead. Give [Font-Awesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/) a try.

Comment: @dowomenfart, It doesn't work :/

Comment: @JamesDonnelly, I prefer a "clean" solution. Thank you!

Comment: Give James solution a try. And font awesome is a clean solution. If you dont want inconsistency.

Comment: When using special html characters you're bound to run into lot's of issues like this. Personally, if something like this happens I leave IE alone, as long as it doesn't look broken - things don't have to be perfect in every browser.

Comment: @AlonShmiel if anything I'd say that an icon-based font would be a cleaner solution. You'll probably find that not all browsers will render those particular Unicode symbols.

Comment: "but in explorer it looks bad" that just browser rendering differences, as suggested try a icon font or svg

Comment: @JamesDonnelly, I take my words back.. your solution is awesome! Thank you! you can answer my question and I will mark it..